# How to trench building front facing elevation to run electric line for my new elevation/facade lights

Tags: electrical, lighting, conduit, building

My building has an beautiful elevation but at night but the lights fixed at the elevation is not enough

and so I'm planning to install few elevation lights but I'd like the conduit to the lights sealed so it's not an eye sore during day time.

My elevation had two layers of Wall putty and paint on top of that. I used scaffold to do this.

But can someone give me some ideas to hide the conduits cheaply without needing extensive repair or expense.

e.g

[image: for example]

If trenching is only way then how to make sure it's not causing any hairline cracks or causing air gaps in the concrete structure.

I can ask some contractor but they also have the habit of taking the approach which is more beneficial to them than the customer.

So trying to do my own research and come up with my plan.

Comment: There are lights fixtures on the building front facing elevation. It's also called as Architectural lighting or facade lighting

Comment: Are you asking how to mount more lights on the front wall of the building without disturbing the front finish of the building? Or are you asking to mount lights in the front yard pointing back at the building?

Comment: @Triplefault - More lights on front wall of the building without disturbing the front finish of the building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment that the new lights will be on the front of the building, I suggest drilling holes through the front of the building to the interior and wiring the new lights from the interior of the building's rooms.

No external "trenching", breaking of the building surface finish, or surface conduits will be needed. Sufficient sealing of the fixtures as they are attached to the building exterior will keep water out. Use approved exterior electrical boxes, and proper wiring treatment to bring the power cables into the walls inside the building. Continue the cables inside the walls down to the electrical panel or to other circuits in the building. Interior walls can be repaired relatively easily after the wiring is complete, depending on the finish inside the rooms.

This is likely duplicating the kind of arrangement already being used by the existing lighting, if the rendered picture shows what the building actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap and best way would be **surface mount conduits**.

I think you don't have any junction box in your building elevation to get connection from then in that case run **Surface Mount Conduit** and paint the conduit with the same color as your building elevation

or

Go for **Solar powered architectural lights** just install that in a place without any wire so it can observe the energy from sun and power the light when sun is not there.

Comment: I have seen solar powered lights but those are not sophisticated like I can turn off at my will and these are expensive and fault prone too